# I want to enter the URL of social media account in a html textbox but it should restrict to Twitter, Facebook, Instagram and YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

For example,it will let me enter the URL twitter.com/USERNAME but it will not let me enter the URL DIFFERENTWEBSITE.com so only Twitter.com/*, Facebook.com/*, Instagram.com/* and YouTube.com/* are allowed (where ‘*’ means they can enter what they want).

Comment: You will have to do regular expression validation. Try out some examples and update the question, with the example, if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva the OP could put all of the URL's (minus the username part) into a dropdownlist and then have a separate textbox to enter usernames.. then concat the username to the selection of the dropdownlist.. but if the OP only wants to use 1 textbox.. then expressions are necessary.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid If you are using only 1 textbox, you will have 2 options. 1. HTML5 pattern matching validation  2. Validate using Javascript by checking the Regular expression of the text entered.

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva That's what I am saying.. if the OP has a dropdownlist of only the URL's such as `www.Twitter.com/` or `www.facebook.com/`.. then a separate textbox for people to enter usernames.. then just concat the username to the value of the selected option of the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow only 4 urls then either you have use regular expression ,which will check wheather those for domains exists in the url, else give the error.

Comment: this should have been a comment

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a dropdown box instead, then the input is restricted to your list

Comment: So is he going to have a selection for each different username that he wants to search for?

Comment: dropdown + textbox + concat then as you mentioned in the main comments